# SQL Server Files in Secondary file group updates much slower from linked server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

My SQL server fact tables are incrementally being updated with reference to a linked server. The queries run routinely on a regular basis and have been executing successfully for a long time.  The execution time for all queries combined is below 5 minutes.  Recently the updates failed because the primary file group reached its limit, even though I set file growth to 'unlimited'.

I thought it would be helpful to move my fact tables to the secondary file in the same file group of my database to allow for growth. I also shrank the database which reduced file sizes (especially the log file) substantially.

I found that my queries were now running extremely slow, some taking up to 2 hours where they had before run in 5 minutes.

I have now moved them back to the database's primary file and completion time is now back to normal.  I do not however understand what went wrong with the distribution of the tables among the database files.

My queries are running because the log file is smaller, but I need to allow for future growth and would like to place some tables in the secondary file if I run out of space again.

Comment: Which are autogrowth settings for your secondary data file and transaction log file? Is [Instant File Initialization](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/instant-file-initialization/) turned on on your server?

Comment: Secondary Data file set to grow by 1MB, Unlimited; Log file set to grow by 10%, limited to 2,097,152MB.  I will experiment with Instant File Initialization.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you Denis.  Instant File Initialization has resolved the performance issues.

Comment: I am still running out of space.  The error message states that the primary file group is full.  However, the directory holding the primary file group now holds only 16G, while the directory for the secondary file group holds 3G of data.  Previously, when all my tables were held in the primary file group that directory went up to 19G at which point I received the error.  Could this be because the two directories are both o the same physical disk?

Comment: which is your server edition? Is it Microsoft SQL Server Express?

Comment: SQL Developer Edition 2014

Comment: I can't figure out what do you mean saying about moving tables between files in the same file group. Is it `DBCC SHRINKFILE ('YourDBFile', EMPTYFILE)` or something? What is your database recovery model? It sounds as if one of your files can't grow because of out of physical space. I guess it is the log file which became big enough so that it couldn't additionly get 10% of its size. Set  some particular value (128Mb for instance) instead of percents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not on my database as I thought, but on the system's tempdb. I added some additional files that point to a different location to the tempdb.  This resolved the space problem.  Thanks to Denis for resolving the performance issue for me.